# React-native Determining whether the code is being debugged remotely or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a reliable way to determine if react-native code is running on the device, or in chrome (remote-debugging) from within the code?

I have some console logs, that are mostly useful in the chrome console, and want to disable them when on the device (they are already disabled for prod builds), as they have a major performance impact outside of remote debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for now:

```
const debuggingEnabled = !!window.navigator.userAgent;
```

As `window.navigator.userAgent` is `undefined` on android and ios

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this what you mean, but I'll give it a shot: I found this hack some time ago

```
const isDebuggingEnabled = (typeof atob !== 'undefined');
```